# getContext () , getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext are not working in Android

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I want to show a `toast` message but `getContext()` in `Toast.makeText((getContext()," Message" , Toat.LENGTH_LONG.show()))` is giving error

> Cannot resolve Method.

The problem is that in which class I want to show the `Toast` message is not `MainActivity` class. This is `AsyncTask` class. Can i show `Toast` message in other classes (other than `MainActivity` class) as the above mentioned problem?

import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.Toast;

```
public class myClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

public myClass(double a, double b,Context context ) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b=b;
    this.context = context;
}


protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               Toast.makeText((getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

**Edit**
I made the constructor (See above code) but in the `MainActivity` class I am calling in this way  `myClassObj = new myClass(a, b,this);` but is giving error

> myClas() in myClass cannot be applied to:
>   Expected        Actual
>   Parameters       Arguments
>   a:      double    a
>   b:      double    b
>   context: android.content.Context this(anonymous...view.View.OnClickListener)

**Edit3**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    myClass Object;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                double age = 16;
                double number = 33;
                Object = new myClass(age,number,this);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

SecondClass.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class myClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        Context context;
        double a;
        double b;
        public myClass(double a, double b,Context context ) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b=b;
            this.context = context;
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText((context), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please show `AsyncTask` code

Comment: if you are trying to show toast in doInBackground() method then you can't.Move your toast to either pre or postExecute() method

Comment: @VivekMishra Yeah I am showing it in `onPostExecute()`. But same error.

Comment: pass a context from activity from which you are starting your asynctask

Comment: @Logic question edited.

Comment: Create constructor and pass context to findProvinceName class. Then use context in Toast.

Comment: Where is `myClassObj = new myClass(a, b,this);` written? Inside `onCreate`?

Comment: Inside `OnClick()` method.

Comment: @KNeerajLal See the **Edit3** in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `this` it refers to the enclosing class. In your case this is `View.OnClickListener`. But you need to pass the context of your Activity.

So you need to call it this way,

```
Object = new myClass(age,number, MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: @K . WTH. Android is so confusing.

Comment: @user6750923 , that is pure JAVA .. this refers to the class in wic it is called. If you instantiate a anonymous class and inside that if u pass this, it refers to that anonymous class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ApplicationClass.getinstance().getApplicationContext();

Comment: What is `ApplicationClass`?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 3**

Do this in your MainActivity:

```
Object = new myClass(age,number,MainActivity.this);
```

And do this in your myClass

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Edit 2**

```
 class MyClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  int SPLASH_SHOW_TIME=3000;

  Context context;

       public MyClass(Context context ) {
        this.context = context;
    }
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(SPLASH_SHOW_TIME);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Created a server socket",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

}

}
```

Comment: What about the `MainActivity`class where I am sending `context`?

Comment: where ever you want to use this class then make that class as context